# Roboflow 'upload' page not able to extract labelmap from data.yaml

Tags: roboflow

On the 'Upload' page in roboflow, I can't load in a yolov5 data.yaml labelmap file to map the class numbers of pre-annotated images to the class names. The page keeps saying 'Processing files'... What should I do?

[Screenshot of uploading yolov5 data.yaml labelmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKfk7.png)

The content structure of `data.yaml` is:

```
names:
- name1
- name2
- name3
nc: 3
```

## Update

---

The above content structure was the cause of the error. The correct file format could be found from the 'Versions' tab, where you can 'Export' and 'download zip to computer'. The `data.yaml` in this file has the following format:

```
train: ../train/images
val: ../valid/images

nc: 3
names: ['class1','class2','class3']
```

Comment: This looks like it could be a big. Which browser are you using. Could you  send a screenshot of the developer tools console to see if it’s throwing an error parsing the file? (By the way, if this question gets closed for not having any code, please repost in our discussion forums: https://discuss.roboflow.com)

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you for your comment. Please see update above. The problem is fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Where did the malformed file come from? Is this something we should add support for parsing or was it a one-off?

Comment: The malformed file came from the 'show download code' option when I export the dataset directly in a Jupyter notebook. So I think this gives a different `data.yaml` file structure than downloading zip to local. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm that sounds unlikely — they’re downloading the same zip file behind the scenes. Are you able to reproduce this reliably?

Comment: Yes as of 2022-03-03, if I paste the export download code in google colab. I get a `data.yaml` with the first format shown in this post. If I instead download zip to computer, I get a `data.yaml` in the second format shown in this post. This is the same regardless of the version of dataset I download.

Comment: I think you must be looking at the wrong spot in the Collab. They're the same zip file in cloud storage. The code snippet is just downloading it behind the scenes & unzipping it.

Comment: Hmm not sure if I'm looking at the wrong spot in colab, it's the only place where I see a data.yaml after running the download code, I'm only reporting what I'm observing. But it's ok.